# Is $2^{o(k)} = 2^{o(3k)}$?

Tags: notation, computational-complexity

I am having a little trouble understanding little-o notation when it appears in the exponent.
I understand the $2^{3k} \notin 2^{o(k)}$ since $2^{o(k)}$ is not an upper bound for $2^{3k}$. But how can I prove\refute a comparison among two $o$ notations?

Is $2^{o(k)} = 2^{o(3k)}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your attempts in the question please. Then I'll answer it happily :)

Comment: Basically, I am trying to do an inclusion-based proof, taking a variable of $2^{o(3k)}$ and show that it belong\not belong to the set $2^{0(k)}$. I really thought I had this figured out with $2^{2k}\in 2^{o(3k)}$ and $2^{2k} \notin 2^{o(k)}$ but I am sure this is true.

Comment: Short answer is: The statements $f(k)=o(k)$ and $f(k)=o(3k)$ are equivalent. (This can be *very* easily shown with the limit definition of $o$.)

Comment: So the idea is to prove $o(k)=o(3k)$ with the limit definition and then claim that the equality remains also as an exponent of $2$?

Comment: I'm not sure what your understanding of $o(k)=o(3k)$ is. If it means $$o(k)=o(3k) \iff (f(k)=o(k)  \Leftrightarrow f(k)=o(3k))$$ then yes. You can remove the base by taking $\log_2$.

Comment: I agree with @ItamarG ... Unless you have a special definition for the meaning of an expression with $o$ in the exponent, then this is exactly the question $o(k) = o(3k)$.